# Using an interface as a key in a hashmap

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I tried to use an interface as a key in a `hashMap` in order to have 1 map for multiple types of keys. The following seems to work.

```
interface Foo {
        void function();
}
static class Bar implements Foo {

      private int id;
    
      public Bar(int id) {
          this.id = id;
      }
    
      @Override
      public void function() {
          System.out.println("this is bar");
      }
    
      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (this == o) return true;
           if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
           Bar bar = (Bar) o;
           return id == bar.id;
       }
    
       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
          return Objects.hash(id);
       }
}
    
public static Map<Foo, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    
     
static class Baz implements Foo {
    String name;
    public Baz(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void function() {
       System.out.println("this is Baz");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Baz baz = (Baz) o;
       return name.equals(baz.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar(123);
    Baz baz = new Baz("some name");

    map.put(bar, 10);
    map.put(baz, 20);
  
    System.out.println(map.get(bar));
 }
```

What I am not sure about is if there is some corner case that would break this map?
Is there a case that having an interface as a key would break down? Could I have done it simpler using generics?

Comment: It sounds a bit strange to have a set of key that are heterogeneous. What if you have `class Babble extends Bar` If somebody threw a Babble in with your Bar's they cannot be equal, even though they have the same id. Maybe use, [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

Comment: @matt: I guess you mean about the equals/hashCode implementation and inheritence. Good point. I wasnt aiming for having `Bar` be extended but on the other hand I don't think I would be able to enforce all classes used as keys to be `final`

Comment: "Is there a case that having an interface as a key would break down?". Sure, if someone implements your interface with bad hashcode/equals. Or simply a mutable class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that's slightly out of the ordinary is that the equals methods have to compare Bar and Baz objects. When a Map only has one type of objects, the check `this.getClass() == that.getClass` in equals method never returns false. You have implemented this correctly though, so you don't have anything to worry about.

You may get more hash collisions than you expect. Imagine you have two classes that both have an int id field and implement hashCode with `Objects.hash(id)` - now objects of different classes with the same ID have the same hash code. If this use case is expected, you can perturb the hash in a way unique to each class, for example by mixing a class-specific constant to the hash:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(1, id);
}

...

@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(2, name);
}
```

Comment: Ah great point! I see now. But would such a constant as 1/2 work? I mean shouldn't it be some prime or random number per class?

Comment: The `Objects.hash` method takes care of that. The current implementation combines two values by multiplying the first value by a prime and adding the second value.

Answer (score 1):

In theory there could be problems with potentially more hash collisions leading to bad performance due to different implementations of `hashCode`, so you need to be careful, and test it with the real data. Other than that it is a valid use case.

Comment: Doesnt everyone generate the `hashCode` via the IDE nowadays? Is the implementation a concern still?

Comment: @Jim If a `hashCode` implementation is proper for a single type, you can expect good hash distribution, and good `HashMap` performance. It's harder to reason about hash distribution for multiple types. Anyway, if you don't intend for `HashMap` to hold significant amount of keys (> 10000) and your `hashCode` methods are ok, it should work ok.

Comment: `It's harder to reason about hash distribution for multiple types.` this is very interesting. Could you please elaborate?